# How to measure monthly download and upload on interface on Mikrotik?

Tags: router

I have a Mikrotik of RB9xx series (mipsbe). I would like to see how much data flow through the router each month.

I don't need anything fancy like flow per user (MAC address) stats, just the whole download / upload number on WAN interface.

In [Mikrotik wiki](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Queue) I've found only some examples that are connected with limiting bandwidth, but that I do not want to do.

Answer (score 2):

While most networking equipment has the ability to see interface statistics (like traffic over a period of time), these counters are generally used for troubleshooting or while you're actively in the switch.  For longer term data from an interface like what you're looking for I strongly suggest a monitoring tool that utilizes SNMP for the job.

Mirkotik has a specific example using MRTG here:
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/SNMP_MRTG

I find this example to be overly complicated but not knowing your environment it's hard to say what you will think.  Personally I suggest, a free tool if you only have this one use case, like PRTG which can be downloaded for free, and remains free unless you monitor more than 30 things with it.

https://shop.paessler.com/shop/standalone_free_license/

Once you have your tool of choice installed, setting up SNMP can be as simple as setting a community string, and setting a target for SNMP traps.  Details on configuring SNMP for your device are here:

http://www.mikrotik.com/testdocs/ros/2.9/root/snmp.php

If you have need of more monitoring than just this one interface, you may want to investigate other tools to fit your specifications.

Comment: Yes, it is very complicated. Isn't it possible to utilize Mikrotik's Queue or any other default function to do this simple measurement?

Comment: Hey Joudicek, look at this thread (https://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-monitor-per-user-bandwidth-3995150.S.81585585), these guys have tons of good ideas.  If you find a way that works for you can you post here so we can either revise my answer so it's helpful to others, or you can post an answer, doesn't matter as long as we end up with a useful answer for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Mikrotik's graphing? (http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Tools/Graphing)

If you need more detailed information i suggest you to use "traffic flow"
(http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/Traffic_Flow)

[PRTG](http://www.it.paessler.com/prtg) or [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) are great products but IMHO are an overkill in your scenario

Answer (score 2):

Mikrotik Graphing only displays download/upload speed, but not the data usage as in how much mb was downloaded/uploaded during a period of time.